# Map arguments in Java

Tags: java

if You wanted to use arguments to put the arguements into à map. How would you do iT? For example, How would use these arguments in a method?

```
 public void  mapMethod (Map<String,Integer> map)

   {
   //code here
    }
```

I have read other questions similar to this, but none of them seem to explain if it this possible.

Comment: can you precise your question?

Comment: `Integer argumentValue = map.get("argumentName");` ?

Comment: Guess you're looking for - 
`Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Comment: Are you asking if you can provide a constructor for a map which takes a map as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, updated the question.

Comment: every edit to question makes it less clear than before, do you want to `get` or `put` arguments?

Comment: @LaurensVanOorschot - Can you explain in plain and simple english what do you want to do?

Comment: Fair enough. Has the updated question clarify?

Comment: @LaurensVanOorschot but that is not map constructor. map constructor looks like what i posted in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this -

```
Map<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("a", new Integer(10));
    put("b", new Integer(5));
}};
```

This is called Double Brace Initialization.

Comment: Actually, the standard calls this an "initializer block"